# Why was Allura surprised by this?

Tags: voltron, voltron-legendary-defender

I was a bit baffled by the end of Season 3. At the end of Season 2, Allura was shocked to find that

> Witch Haggar was really an Altaen

But in the Season 3 ender, Coran tells everyone the story of how

> Zarkon married the Altean scientist Honerva (who would become Haggar), and that love and devotion was what ultimately got him corrupted into the power-hungry monster he has become.

So, if Coran knows this, why was Allura surprised?

Comment: Just because Coran knew (because he was there) doesn't mean Allure knew. And it is a pretty black mark on Altean history, she was likely kept from being told (probably by her father's order, since he was there, too). And her father's memories in the castle's AI were lost to her early in the show, before it could reveil very much to her

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's pretty obvious to the viewer that Honerva became Haggar, the episode [*Bloodlines* (S05E05)](http://voltron.wikia.com/wiki/Bloodlines) makes it pretty clear that it is not common knowledge at all. It seems that everyone assumes that Honerva died and that Haggar is a completely different person - including Lotor, himself.

> *Lotor*: The union between Zarkan and Honerva sparked a technical revolution within the empire. Even back then, Altean culture was remarkably advanced. The kinds of experiments she was conducting... she advanced science by eons.
>
> *Allura*: How did Haggar get her hands on this?
>
> *Lotor*: She was constantly seeking Altean magical knowledge that she could pervert for her own power. There must have been things that she was unable to access.
>
> *Allura*: I'm going to continue the search.

<snip>

> *Allura*: What's the matter?
>
> *Lotor*: By the end of these logs, it's like they're written by a different person. She's frantic, paranoid, erratic. Her reason and intellect are gone, replaced by fear and paranoia.
>
> *Allura*: Lotor, have you ever wondered... what if Honerva became corrupted the same way Zarkon did? Perhaps she didn't die. What if she and Haggar are the same--
>
> *Lotor*: --That witch is not my mother.

What, exactly, the public knows about Haggar is unclear (e.g. her Altean origins), so it makes sense that Allura might be surprised to learn that Haggar is an Altean as well.

Comment: Even Haggar herself seems to have forgotten some of it

Answer (score 3):

Season 8 appears to offer a definitive answer to this.

> Honerva lost her memories due to her exposure to the quintessence and the birth of Lotor. Zarkon asks her who she is and she has no memories. At that point, she became Hagar and Zarkon lead everyone to believe that Honerva was dead. Lotor even asks Zarkon about his mother at one point and all he says is "she was his greatest disappointment".
> The presumptive belief is that Honerva died in childbirth. As such, Coran and even Allura knew full well that Zarkon had married her and that she had done all that research, but believed her dead. Allura's shock at Hagar being Altean is partially due to her believing that she and Coran were the last of their race. Why she didn't connect the dots then is unclear.